# How to stretch a UIImage to fit text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage

I am implementing a tag system into my app, and for this to happen I need a background image of the tag and the text to overlay that image. The problem is though - how can I stretch the image to 'fit' the text? 'Maths' works fine, but a word like 'Economics' would not as it would overlap the background image.

This is what my tag looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to calculate the expected size of text and then give frame to image accordingly.You can use the image with cap width and cap height if required. Here is the code snippet.

```
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(600,52);  // maximum possible size
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [brandName sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica-Bold" size:20] 
                                     constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation]; 

    UIImage *centerStretchedImage =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, expectedLabelSize.width+20,52);
    UIImageView *dynamicImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    dynamciImage.image = centerStretchedImage;
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess it to use stretchable images, these are just plain image where you set the part that iOS can stretch.

These image are easy to make:

```
UIImage *imageTemp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonBackground.png"];

// For iOS 4.3 and lower
UIImage *stretchableImage = [imageTemp stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:10];

// if you are targetting iOS 5 and higher
UIImage *stretchableImage = [imageTemp resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];
```

The `20` and `10` are just example, they may be different for you images. If these are `UIButton` the you can just set the stretchable image as the background of the button and it will correctly grow with the button. If you are setting the text from code for a `UILabel` you can use the `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` to calculate the with of the string. and then set the correct size of the image.

Comment: From [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload) _stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth : Creates and returns a new image object with the specified cap values. (Deprecated in iOS 5.0. Deprecated. Use the resizableImageWithCapInsets: instead, specifying cap insets such that the interior is a 1x1 area.)_

Comment: Yes your are correct, but if you are targeting iOS 4.3 also you might want to use `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: topCapHeight:`.

Comment: True, ONLY if we are targeting iOS 4.3 onwards. For iOS 5.0 onwards, this is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the string width (may be UILabel in your case) like below

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font 
                        constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                        lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

Once text length is known you can use that and set the background as stretchable image.

```
UIImage *strechableImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tagImage"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 3, 3, 25)]
```

The Insets (caps) are (top,left,bottom,top) and defines the area that is not scaled/stretched (e.g. rounded corners).

From Apple documentation

During scaling or resizing of the image, areas covered by a cap are not scaled or resized. Instead, the pixel area not covered by the cap in each direction is tiled, left-to-right and top-to-bottom, to resize the image.